# Accessing what looks like a pop up but apparently isn't

Tags: python, selenium, alert

I am working my way through a website making a reservation. Upon completing the reservation a box pops up (that looks like an alert) titled request complete (html follows). [image]

I have tried to access it as if it was an alert and consistently get a no alert present exception. I have read all i can find and learned that recent HTML changes allow items to be displayed that look like pop ups but are not (see [https://www.eviltester.com/webdriver/faqs/why-does-selenium-not-work-with-this-alert/#:~:text=Q%3A%20%E2%80%9CWhy%20does%20Selenium%20not%20work%20with%20my,of%20the%20web%20has%20changed.%20HTML%20has%20changed.](https://www.eviltester.com/webdriver/faqs/why-does-selenium-not-work-with-this-alert/#:%7E:text=Q%3A%20%E2%80%9CWhy%20does%20Selenium%20not%20work%20with%20my,of%20the%20web%20has%20changed.%20HTML%20has%20changed.)).

AS a result i have changed the python code to use a find_element(By.CLASS_NAME) syntax and i am able to find the element

```
sleep(5)
    try:
        br.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-button-text")
        print ("found the continue button")
        return 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ("Did not find continue button")
        return 0
```

However when i try to execute a click as follows:

```
sleep(5)
    try:
        br.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-button-text").click()
        print ("found the continue button")
        return 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ("Did not find continue button")
        return 0
```

I get an element not interactable message.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (tee_time_thread):

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\Projects\Automated Tee Times\New Automated 22-09-14.py", line 1456, in tee_time_thread
        result = commit_time(self, br, thread)
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\Projects\Automated Tee Times\New Automated 22-09-14.py", line 330, in commit_time
        br.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-button-text").click()
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\Projects\updatefoursomes\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 88, in click
        self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\Projects\updatefoursomes\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
        return self._parent.execute(command, params)
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\Projects\updatefoursomes\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\MyStuff\Python310\Projects\updatefoursomes\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wait for element to be clickable.
Use Webdriverwait() and wait for element to be clickable and use the following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(br,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.//span[text()='Continue']]"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Using above solution, if you are still getting `element not interactable` then try with javascripts executor or action class.

```
elementbtn=WebDriverWait(br,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.//span[text()='Continue']]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementbtn)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, but i wanted to be thorough. I made the suggested change (see code) but i am getting a timeout exception. Any other suggesteions would be appreciated - maybe the xpath is off?          WebDriverWait(br,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.//span[text='Continue']]")))

Comment: @steve, may be the element is inside an `iframe` . can you please check parent node of the button with any `ifame` tag, If so you need to switch to iframe first, in order to access the element.